# apache openmeetings integration with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, video-conferencing, openmeetings

I want to build a vido conference solution using apache openmeetings , does any one knows a good tutorial to do that ? also i want to integrate it with JSP. i search on the web but it seems that there is a few resource on it . blogs , books , or article is accepted .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should join:
http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/mail-lists.html
to discuss that.

There are some examples for the:
http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/SoapRestAPI.html
I think the Jira/Confluence Integration also uses JSP/Servlets to integrate Openmeetings.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a any tutorial for the same. But you can use REST API to connect with Openmeeting using webservice. 
Below question itself will give you some idea. [Apache Open Meeting Integration with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258420/apache-open-meeting-integration-with-php/28446661#28446661)