# Apache Open Meeting Integration with PHP

Tags: php, openmeetings

Background: I am working on the apache open meeting integration with my php site. I am very new to apache open meeting and also with REST API.

Questions: I have successfully logged into open meeting server and I am able to create new room ids programmatically through REST. But I dont know how to show the conference room in my php page itself. I have seen that, moodle and joomla have such functionality. Do I need to use iframes? how to keep the session for that page?

Thanks in advance